# PHP avoid recursion in magic methods

Tags: php, magic-methods

I haven't found an exact duplicate of the question I'm posting here, so here it is:

```
class CBaseEntity
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        $property = "m_".$property;
        echo $property;
        if(property_exists($this, $property))
        {           
            $result = $this->$property;
            return $result;
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception("Property not found $property");
        }
    }
}

class CCategoryEntity extends CBaseEntity
{
    private $m_id;
    private $m_name;
    private $m_description;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public static function CreateFromParams($id,$name, $description)
    {
        $instance = new CCategoryEntity();
        $instance->m_id=$id;
        $instance->m_name=$name;
        $instance->m_description=$description;
        return $instance;
    }

    public static function CreateFromArray(array $catData)
    {
        $instance = new CCategoryEntity();
        $instance->m_id = $catData["id"];
        $instance->m_name = $catData["name"];
        $instance->m_description = $catData["description"];
        return $instance;
    }
}

    $categoryEntity = CCategoryEntity::CreateFromParams(3, "EntityA", "Entity");
    echo $categoryEntity->name;

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Property not found m_m_name'
 Exception: Property not found m_m_name in ***\models\BaseModel.php on line 33
```

It appears that the `name` property is resolved via the `get` magic method, but the return in the body of this getter will again issue a call to itself instead of, somehow, intelligently stopping as the string in `$property` coincides with the name of the sought attribute. I could do a string compare and see if the property starts with `m_`, but I don't want a second call being issued already in this case.

There are other SO questions involving similar code that does not yield unnecessary recursion. Did something change in php or is this the default behaviour? What can be done to reach the goal intended by this design in an elegant way?

Comment: So where's the recursion?

Comment: There is no recursion here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2QSlzz BTW you are missing closing parenthesis in `if` line, so you may present some actual code if in fact it recurses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion appears because you are checking only if property exists, not if it is accessible from current scope. Since it is declared private, it is not accessible from parent or child classes, only in class where it was declared, thats why `__get` is called second time (first was for non-existent property, now it is for inaccessible one). Try out [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to get accessible properties.

You may want to make it protected, or define public getter methods for private properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the solution!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean but there's no second call. When you access the property outside the class, `__get()` will be called just once. `$this->$property` inside the `__get()` method does not trigger another call.

From the PHP documentation:

> The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties
>   or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the
>   current scope.

this means that the `__get()` method is called only when there is no property available for that call.

Comment: I'm extending a base class that owns this getter magic method. Via pseudopolymorphism I hoped to inherit a properly functioning magic method. Sorry for not explaining the entire bollocks.

Comment: @teodron, you should create a new question. your edit does change way too much of the original question.